# Displaying mathematical equation inside the table output in R

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, equation

I have a mathematical equation that I would like to include inside a cell of an output table in R-markdown:

```
'$\\sum_{l=1}^g -g\\$'
```

The table code is here:

```
tb1 = data.frame(c("Treatment","Residual","Total"),
               c(1,2,3),
               c(4,5,6))
```

The equation should replace value "3" in the last column of the second row.

How can that be achieved?

Comment: is your data frame correctly specified? Possibly you mean something like: tb1 = data.frame(Treatment=c(1,4), Residual=c(2,5), Total=c(3,6)).

Answer (score 1):

Redefining the sample data as:

```
tb1 = data.frame(Treatment=c(1,4), Residual=c(2,5), Total=c(3,6))
```

Include the latex equation in the data frame as you've specified it, quoting the backslash:

```
tb1 = data.frame(Treatment=c(1,4), Residual=c(2,5), 
Total=c("$\\sum_{l=1}^g -g$",6))
```

Then use print.xtable to generate the correct latex markup. An rmarkdown code chunk might look as follows:

````
```{r echo=F, results='asis'}
library(xtable)

print(xtable(tb1), sanitize.text.function = function(x) {x})
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rrrl}
\hline
& Treatment & Residual & Total \\ 
\hline
1 & 1.00 & 2.00 & $\sum_{l=1}^g -g$ \\ 
2 & 4.00 & 5.00 & 6 \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```
````

Answer (score 1):

`knitr::kable` provides the functionality to input the equation into the cell directly, in combination with the `escape = FALSE` argument (see [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_html.html#celltext_specification)). This prevents the need for you to provide the escape in the document generation (but you still need to provide the escape for R with the sum).

For your case (in a code chunk)

```
tb1 = data.frame(c("Treatment","Residual","Total"),
           c(1,2,"$\\sum_{l=1}^g-g$"),
           c(4,5,6))
knitr::kable(tb1, escape = FALSE)
```